# Unable to create a new account into QB Desktop via Intuit Data Services and Sync Manager (using IntuitDataSyncEngine)

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I am posting (using POST method) this request (for new account) to url https://services.intuit.com/sb/account/v2/570357950

123456789         CurrentAccount      true      Expense      Expense      1111

But getting this error :

### 500 - Internal server error.

#### There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

I am using Intuit OAuth API console to post the request for testing.
Although I'm able to GET data from QB desktop (Via IDS and Sync Manager) in same scenario.

Any Solution?

Comment: As a side note - Intuit Data Services/Intuit Partner Platform has been a gigantic joke lately - it's buggy, unmaintained, and the next-generation APIs Intuit has been promising are vaporware. If you're developing for QuickBooks for Windows, you might want to consider looking at the QuickBooks Web Connector/SDK instead.

Comment: yes, I am developing QB for windows. What about SDK? do u have details about SDK and also for WebConnector?

Comment: When was the last time you tried this request? If that is a valid realmID, I am not seeing any connections or attempts to connect to it during the last 30 days.

Comment: this is the URL with valid realm id: https://services.intuit.com/sb/account/v2/570357960 working for get but not for post (not creating new objects)

Comment: If you changed something, then post your new HTTP request and HTTP response. Preferably the entire HTTP request/response, instead of the mangled half-request you posted above.

Comment: Web Connector overview: http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_web_connector and SDK: https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0085_QuickBooks_Windows_SDK/010_qb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Issue resolved.
Use this new utilty from intuit to test: http://apiexplorer.developer.intuit.com

Answer (score 0):

That URL isn't a valid to POST data to.

If you refer to [the documentation](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0050_Data_Services/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0100_Calling_Data_Services/0011_Creating_an_Object) you'll notice that the correct URL format for creating accounts is:

```
https://services.intuit.com/sb/<objectName>/v2/<realmID>
```

The URL you're using is:

```
https://services.intuit.com/sb/account/v2/
```

Which is missing the  component (it should be an integer about 6 to 12 digits)

Fix your URL.

Comment: thanks for reply..although I am using the correct url and getting the error. URL: https://services.intuit.com/sb/account/v2/570357950 and yes you are right that was missing realmID. I have checked that at https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0050_Data_Services/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0600_Object_Reference/Account but still I am getting the error.